# Trying to Select 20 items with the Highest TimeStamp Value and Lowest ID Value?

Tags: php, mysql, phpmyadmin

I am trying to select rows with the 20 highest 'TimeStamp' value, and from those 20 rows the 1 row with the lowest ID value:

```
$result_last = mysql_query("SELECT * FROM (SELECT * FROM Events ORDER BY TimeStamp DESC LIMIT 20) ORDER BY ID ASC LIMIT 1");
```

The above query doesn't work, but it makes sense to me. Is there something wrong with this query?

Comment: What do you mean it doesn't work. Does it return an error? Does it return the wrong data?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The error is `#1248 - Every derived table must have its own alias` and this is indeed true. This should work:

```
$result_last = mysql_query("SELECT * FROM (SELECT * FROM Events ORDER BY TimeStamp DESC LIMIT 20) AS T ORDER BY ID ASC LIMIT 1");
```

Comment: Great. Thank you for the help! you nailed that error. I will accept when it lets me

Answer (score -2):

Try something like this:

```
$result_last = mysql_query("SELECT * FROM Events WHERE TimeStamp IN(SELECT TimeStamp FROM Events ORDER BY TimeStamp DESC LIMIT 10") ORDER BY TimeStamp ASC LIMIT 1);
```

Comment: I dont think mySQL supports IN?